# What is the physical location of the U1A symbol on Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm trying to find an easy way to allow an Arduino Uno to determine if it's being powered from USB or the DC barrel jack. In [this thread](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=120693.0), one user recommends wiring the output of the on-board comparator op-amp (U5A pin 1) into the digital input pin.

I couldn't find U5A on the [current schematic](http://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf), but I think he's actually referring to U1A pin 1. Is this correct?

Unfortunately, I'm not sure where on the physical Arduino that device is located. I have one in front of me, and almost none of the parts are labeled on the silk screen. How do I find out where it is? I've googled for Arduino Uno part placement schematics, but all I'm finding are blurry unlabeled low-res images.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The op-amp is a LM358 so you can look at the ICs themselves. Also it's a dual comparator with 8 pins. On my example image below you can see it below the crystal. I can't comment if that's the correct way to sense what you need, but it seems the comparator output should be 1 if there is external power applied. You could check with a multimeter.

[image]